# JSF 2 DataTable - all exisintg items are being reset to new Item() after clicked on commandlink

Tags: jsf

Couldn't quite figure out why all existing items in datatable are being reset to new Item() after I clicked the commandlink.  This app gives user a list of contacts along with an Edit (commandlink) button that user can click to change the selected item into edit mode.  when I click on the commandlink, it call the bean's edit() and the getRowData() is getting the expected row.  But the exist data in the row is somehow blank (new MSAMContactJTO() to be exact).  In fact, all existing rows in the datatable are showhow being reset to blank.

Below is the xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">

<!-- saved from url=(0049)http://usmodev/my_send_a_message/address_book.htm -->
<h:head><title>My Send a Message</title>
</h:head> 

<h:body>  

<h:form id="addressBookForm" prependId="false">
  <h:dataTable id="contactListTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" 
    value="#{MSAMAddressBook2ListBean.contactListTable}"
    rendered="#{not empty MSAMAddressBook2ListBean.contactList}"  
    var="item">

    <h:column>
      <h:panelGrid id="contactNameColumn" >
        <h:panelGroup style="text-align:left; white-space:nowrap;" rendered="#{!item.editMode    and !item.newAdd}">
          <h:outputText value="#{item.contactName}"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
       <h:panelGroup style="text-align:left; white-space:nowrap;" rendered="#{item.editMode || item.newAdd}">
         <h:inputText  id="contactName" value="#{item.contactName}" maxlength="30" size="30" />
       </h:panelGroup>
      </h:panelGrid>

    </h:column>

    <h:column>
      <h:panelGrid id="actionColumn" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <h:commandLink id="editContact" action="#{MSAMAddressBook2ListBean.edit}"  value="EDIT"/>
        <!-- f:ajax event="action" execute="@form" render="contactListTable"/ -->
      </h:panelGrid>    
    </h:column>
  </h:dataTable>
</h:form> 

</h:body>
</html>
```

Below is the manage bean:

```
package com.arch.myaccount.jsf;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.arch.database.myaccount.MSAMAddressBookDatabase;
import com.arch.myaccount.MSAMContactDTO;

import javax.faces.model.DataModel;
import javax.faces.model.ListDataModel;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@ManagedBean(name="MSAMAddressBook2ListBean")
@ViewScoped
public class MSAMAddressBook2ListBean extends JSFBean implements Serializable 
{

    // table list info
    private transient DataModel<MSAMContactJTO> contactListTable;
    private ArrayList<MSAMContactJTO> contactList = null;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        getContactList();
    }

    public String edit() {

        String result = "successful";

        MSAMContactJTO item = getContactListTable().getRowData();
        item.setEditMode(true);

        return result;
    }


    public List<MSAMContactJTO> getContactList() {
        if (contactList == null) {
        try {
             loadContactList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {}
        }

        return contactList;
    }

    public void loadContactList() {

        try {
            List<MSAMContactDTO> contacts = new MSAMAddressBookDatabase().findContactsByLoginName(getLoginID());
            if (contactList == null) contactList = new ArrayList<MSAMContactJTO>(); 
            else contactList.clear();

            for (MSAMContactDTO contact :contacts) {
                MSAMContactJTO abDTO = new MSAMContactJTO();
                abDTO.copyFromMSAMContactDTO(contact);
                contactList.add(abDTO);
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            addFatalMessage("We are unable to fulfill your request.  Please try again later");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public DataModel<MSAMContactJTO> getContactListTable() {
        if (contactListTable == null) {
            contactListTable = new ListDataModel<MSAMContactJTO>(contactList);
        }
            return contactListTable;
    }

    public void setContactList(ArrayList<MSAMContactJTO> contactList) {
        this.contactList = contactList;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just noticed that if I change it to sessionscope, it works.

Comment: The problem turn out to be me not setting up the JSF2.0 in Websphere correctly.  It works fine after I following the setup instruction from:http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.etools.jsf.doc%2Ftopics%2Ftcrtfaceletproject.html